# Show products based on category slug in Django 3

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have created a category and subcategory in a project and it is showing as I wanted, but now having a little difficulty in getting the products to the category page.

I have a parent category and sub-category but not in all cases will the parent category have a subcategory.

###### models.py | Category Model

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=25)
   parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='children', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)



class Meta:
      verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
      ordering = ('name',)
  


def __str__(self): 
      return self.name
```

###### Product Model

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=110)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

###### views.py

```
def home(request):
   products = Product.objects.all().order_by('?')
   categories = Category.objects.all()
   featured_products = Product.objects.filter(is_featured=True)


   context = {
      'products':products,
      'categories':categories,
      'featured_products':featured_products
   }
   return render(request, "store/home.html", context)
```

Below is my HTML code

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="main-nav">
       <ul class="menu sf-arrows">
          <li class=""><a href="{% url 'home-page' %}">Home</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="{% url 'about-page' %}">About</a></li>
          <li class=""><a href="{% url 'home-page' %}">Services</a></li>
          {% for category in categories %}
             {% if category.parent == None %}
                {% if category.parent.children %}
                   <li><a href="{{category.get_absolute_url }}" class="sf-with-ul">{{category.name}}</a>
                {% else %}
                   <li><a href="{{category.get_absolute_url }}" class="">{{category.name}}</a>
                {% endif %}
                   <ul>
                      {% for subcategory in category.children.all %}
                         <li><a href="{{sucategory.slug}}">{{subcategory.name}}</a></li>
                      {% endfor %}
                   </ul>
                </li>
             {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          <li class=""><a href="{% url 'contact-page' %}">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>
```

#Category.html

```
<div class="col-lg-9 main-content">
      <div class="row row-sm">
         <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
            {% for i in category_products %}
               <div class="product-default">
                     <figure>
                        <a href="product.html">
                           <img src="{{i.display_img.url}}">
                        </a>
                     </figure>
                     <div class="product-details">
                        <div class="ratings-container">
                           <div class="product-ratings">
                                 <span class="ratings" style="width:100%"></span><!-- End .ratings -->
                                 <span class="tooltiptext tooltip-top"></span>
                           </div><!-- End .product-ratings -->
                        </div><!-- End .product-container -->
                        <h2 class="product-title">
                           <a href="product.html">{{i.name}}</a>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="price-box">
                           <span class="product-price">$9.00</span>
                        </div><!-- End .price-box -->
                        <div class="product-action">
                           <a href="#" class="btn-icon-wish"><i class="icon-heart"></i></a>
                           <button class="btn-icon btn-add-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addCartModal"><i class="icon-bag"></i>ADD TO CART</button>
                           <a href="ajax/product-quick-view.html" class="btn-quickview" title="Quick View"><i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a> 
                        </div>
                     </div><!-- End .product-details -->
               </div>
            {% endfor %}
         </div>
      </div>

      <nav class="toolbox toolbox-pagination">
         <div class="toolbox-item toolbox-show">
            <label>Showing 1–9 of 60 results</label>
         </div><!-- End .toolbox-item -->

         <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item disabled">
                  <a class="page-link page-link-btn" href="#"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item active">
                  <a class="page-link" href="#">1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
            <li class="page-item"><span>...</span></li>
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">15</a></li>
            <li class="page-item">
                  <a class="page-link page-link-btn" href="#"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
</div><!-- End .col-lg-9 -->
```

I wish to filter products based on parent category and subcategory. If the parent category is selected, it should bring all products under the parent category and the same for the subcategoruies. Please any help on the views.py function for this???

Comment: Update context key name for `categories` from `category` to `categories` so that you can use it in html as `{% for category in categories %}` instead of `{% for category in category %}` which is not correct.

Comment: I've done but that is not what am looking for. I want to fetch products on category page when a category is selected and is subcategory, all the products in that subcategory should be displayed. I've added my category.html page.